# How do I identify and label anomaly in a sequence of every nth elements in column / an array or the 'odd one out ' in every group of five

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns `group`, `ref`. In the `ref` column, I am interested in identifying the `anomalies` or `odd_one_out` based on the `preceding` and `following` elements for every five-element in a dataset - example `[Y,Y,N,Y,Y]` `N` is the anomaly or `[N,N,N,Y,N]` the anomaly is `Y` in the case. The `ref` helps to compare and match the `pred`.
For every set of five values, there is an `odd_one_out` or `anomaly` element

Note: the dataframe has 340000 rows - however, I am interested in every five-element (340000/5) hence the `group 1-5`.

```
df

group, ref 
1,  Y
2,  Y
3,  Y
4,  N
5,  Y
1,  Y
2,  Y
3,  N
4,  Y
5,  N
```

Below is my desired outcome:
I want to label the anomaly as `'x'` in the `anomaly` column

```
Final_df 

group, ref, anomaly

1, Y, NaN 
2, Y, NaN
3, Y, NaN
4, N, 'x'
5, Y, NaN
1, Y, NaN
2, Y, NaN
3, N, 'x'
4, Y, NaN
5, N, NaN
```

`NaN` is to represent missing values in the `anomaly` column or otherwise leave blank

Here is my code

```
def list_slice(S, step):
    return [S[i::step] for i in range(step)]
print(list_slice(pred,5))

df['anomaly']= anomaly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in one line

**Following your edit. This should work**

```
df['anomaly']=df.ref.replace(['Y','N'], ['NaN','x'])
```

**If you keep original question where**

```
print(df)

   group ref, pred
0    1,   Y,    Y
1    2,   Y,    Y
2    3,   Y,    Y
3    4,   Y,    N
4    5,   Y,    Y
5    1,   Y,    Y
6    2,   Y,    Y
7    3,   Y,    N
8    4,   Y,    Y
9    5,   N,    N
```

**Solution**

```
df['anomaly']=pd.Series(np.where(df.iloc[:,-2:].replace(['Y,','Y','N,','N'],[True, True, False, False]).nunique(1).eq(2),'x',np.nan))

    group ref, pred anomaly
0    1,   Y,    Y     nan
1    2,   Y,    Y     nan
2    3,   Y,    Y     nan
3    4,   Y,    N       x
4    5,   Y,    Y     nan
5    1,   Y,    Y     nan
6    2,   Y,    Y     nan
7    3,   Y,    N       x
8    4,   Y,    Y     nan
9    5,   N,    N     nan
```

**How it works;**

```
#df.replace(-the datset is dirty. I get rid of  the commas indf.ref as I simultaneously convert Y into True and N into false

g=df.iloc[:,-2:].replace(['Y,','Y','N,','N'],[True, True, False, False])

#g.nunique(1) ccounts the unique values in rowwise

g.nunique(1)

#np.where(condition, answer if condition is true, answer if condition is false) helps me populate x and NaN

aaray=np.where(g.nunique(1).eq(2),'x',np.nan)

#pd.Series(array) converts array into df column
```

Answer (score 2):

Just comparing the `ref` and `pred` column gives the result you desire.

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[1,'Y','Y'],[2,'Y','Y'],[3,'Y','Y'],[4,'Y','N'],[5,'Y','Y'],
             [1,'Y','Y'],[2,'Y','Y'],[3,'Y','N'], [4,'Y','Y'], [5,'N','N']],
            columns = ['group', 'ref', 'pred'])

a['anomaly'] = a['ref'] == a['pred']






    group   ref     pred    anomaly
0   1   Y   Y   True
1   2   Y   Y   True
2   3   Y   Y   True
3   4   Y   N   False
4   5   Y   Y   True
5   1   Y   Y   True
6   2   Y   Y   True
7   3   Y   N   False
8   4   Y   Y   True
9   5   N   N   True
```

Comment: ignore the `ref` column , I am more interested in the `pred` column, I want to compare before and after values, for every five elements, they are supposed to have same values for  example -         `[ 'Y','Y','Y','N',Y] `  `N` is the odd one out

Comment: Suppose I ignore the `ref` column, the first group is `Y Y Y N Y` out of which the fourth instance is odd one out. But in the second group `Y Y N Y N`, you only pick the third `N` as odd and ignore the fifth `N`. Even if the odd instance is the  one with 2/5 occurrence, how did you decide which of the two Ns is the odd one?